# can not find cpu threads in system monitor?

Tags: intel-cpu

I run ubuntu 21.10 and have a 4 core processor with 4 threads, but I only get 4 cores:

[image]

Comment: What were you expecting to see? As you said, you have 4 cores and you see 4 cores. Yes, each of those cores has virtual cores, but they are not actual CPUs so won't be shown there.

Answer (score 0):

You want to read/read/ged only core number info from those tool, @Sara.

Here's my 4 Core/8 Thread CPU.

[image]

If you need to see another info from there, i suggest you follow tutorials like [this](https://mmikowski.github.io/ksysguard-config/) (just find one for you task manager environment tool)